# java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionSynchronization.afterCommit()V

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am creating a  Spring MVC web application. I am giving HttpRequest to my App-

http://localhost:8080/MVC_CRUD_SPRING/add

Below is the code I have written in the EmployeeController which handles request with path '/add'

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView addEmployee(EmployeeBean employeeBean,BindingResult bindingResult){
    Map<String, Object> model=new HashMap<String,Object>();
    model.put("employees", prepareListOfEmployeeBeans(employeeService.listEmployees()));
    return new ModelAndView("addEmployee","command",model);
}
```

After hitting the URL while debugging the code I could see the employee objects being retrieved successfully.

[image]

But post this I am getting below error and request to failed to render requested page, The error is saying call is being made to abstract method

```
Apr 01, 2015 3:28:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [employee] in context with path  [/MVC_CRUD_SPRING] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionSynchronization.afterCommit()V] with root cause
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionSynchronization.afterCommit()V
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.invokeAfterCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:133)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerAfterCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:121)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerAfterCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:951)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:797)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:724)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:475)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:270)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
```

Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Most likely a spring version error. Whats the version spring-tx*.jar and spring-orm*.jar. If possible please provide your library jars list

Comment: spring-tx-3.2.4.jar and spring-orm-1.2.2.jar

Comment: List of jars as follows

Comment: antlr-2.7.7.jar,
aopalliance-.jar,
asm-3.1.jar,
asm-attrs-1.5.3.jar,
avro-1.5.1.jar,
c3p0-0.9.1.jar,
cglib-nodep-2.2.jar,
commons-collections-3.1.jar,
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar,
dom4j-1.6.1.jar,
ehcache-1.2.3.jar,
ejb3-persistence-1.0.2.GA.jar,
glassfish-api-4.0-b77.jar,
hibernate-3.2.4.ga.jar,
hibernate-annotations-3.2.1.ga.jar,
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar,

Comment: jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar,
javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar,
jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar,
jdbc-stdext-2.0.jar,
jstl-1.2.jar,
jta-1.1.jar,
log4j-1.2.13.jar,
lucene-core-3.5.0.jar,
mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar,
org.springframework.web-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar,
org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.j,
paranamer-2.3.jar,
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar,
snappy-java-1.0.1-rc3.jar,
spring-aop-3.2.4.RELEASE-javadoc.jar,
spring-aop-3.2.4.RELEASE-sources.jar,

Comment: spring-aop-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar,
spring-aspects-3.2.4.RELEASE-javadoc.jar,
spring-aspects-3.2.4.RELEASE-sources.jar,
spring-aspects-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar,
spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE-javadoc.jar,
spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE-sources.jar,
spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar,
spring-build-src-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar,
spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE-javadoc.jar,
spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE-sources.jar,
spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar,
spring-context-support-3.2.4.RELEASE-javadoc.jar,
spring-context-support-3.2.4.RELEASE-sources.jar,

Comment: spring-context-support-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar,
spring-core-3.2.4.RELEASE-javadoc.jar,
spring-core-3.2.4.RELEASE-sources.jar,
spring-core-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar,
spring-expression-3.2.4.RELEASE-javadoc.jar,
spring-expression-3.2.4.RELEASE-sources.jar,
spring-expression-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar,
spring-hibernate3-2.0-m4.jar,
spring-jdbc-3.2.4.release.jar,
spring-orm-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar,
spring-tx-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar,
spring-webmvc-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar